# Yii2: Strategy for avoiding InputWidget id conflicts

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2, yii2-widget

When rendering an [InputWidget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-inputwidget.html) in Yii2 an `id` options HTML tag is automatically generated based on an internal static widget instance counter. By default the `id`s will look like `w0`, `w1`, `w2`, ... depending on how many widgets were instantiated. This works great when rendering the whole page at once.

But it quickly becomes problematic when introducing partial rendering (such as AJAX), because every sequential page render will begin with the widget counter at `0`, so if we inject such widgets into an already-rendered page, we will end up with id conflicts (eg. we might have two widgets with the same id `w0`). This breaks HTML standards, causes JavaScript issues and other headaches.

So what are the possibilities around this?

- The most obvious way around this is of course manually setting the `id` to a hardcoded string. But now we need to know how many times the widget will be rendered, and we need to add a lot of `if` statements to determine which ID to render. It works but it's very hacky.
- Automatically prepending or appending the widget `id` with the `id` of its parent container. This sounds nice in theory, but I haven't been able to realize it so far.
- Modifying Yii2 `InputWidget` to use a UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) instead of a counter. This sounds promising, but it requires a core framework patch (otherwise it won't work for 3rd party widgets) and makes it impossible to predict the ids (e.g. when testing).

What is the most *universal* solution for this?

Comment: I ran into this problem this week also. Been busy with it since a couple of days now. Can't realy find a suitable way to do this. I just hardcode it for now in all my third-party widgets. For my own widgets that extend InputWidget, I've build my own InputWidget that extends InputWidget on its own and handles the id generation itself. The autoGenerateId method of the Widget class is very frustrating if i must say..